# How to configure Spring XML for SQL Server (Windows Authentication)?

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, jdbc

I do not know how to connect with SQL Server using Spring XML and Windows Authentication. It throws an error saying

> Property 'driverClassName' threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class
>   [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver]".

I also added in Gradle this library.

This is my spring-mvc-demo-servlet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:ca="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

<!-- Step 3: Add support for component scanning -->
<context:component-scan base-package="pl.c" />

<!-- Step 4: Add support for conversion, formatting and validation support -->
<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<!-- Step 5: Define Spring MVC view resolver -->
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<!-- Database DataSource -->
<bean id="myDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;integratedSecurity=true;" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="pl.c.entity" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="myTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="myTransactionManager" />

<mvc:resources mapping="/view-additions/**" location="view-additions/" />
```

Gradle configuration:

```
plugins {
id 'war'
id 'java'
}

group 'pl.c.wct'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '5.4.0.Final'
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '5.1.44'
    compile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'servlet-api', version: '2.5'
    compile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version: '4.0.1'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-webmvc', version: '5.1.3.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'jstl', version: '1.2'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-validator', version: '6.0.13.Final'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-orm', version: '5.1.3.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'com.microsoft.sqlserver', name: 'mssql-jdbc', version: '7.0.0.jre8'
    compile group: 'commons-dbcp', name: 'commons-dbcp', version: '1.4'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-dbcp2', version: '2.5.0'
    compile group: 'commons-pool', name: 'commons-pool', version: '1.6'
    compile group: 'commons-collections', name: 'commons-collections', version: '3.2.2'
}
```

This is stacktrace:

```
[..]
    16-Jan-2019 18:15:33.691 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-3] org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean Initializing Servlet 'dispatcher'
    16-Jan-2019 18:15:33.792 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-3] org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myDataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
    PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'driverClassName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver]
    16-Jan-2019 18:15:33.792 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-3] org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean Context initialization failed
     org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myDataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
    PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'driverClassName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1685)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1400)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:575)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:846)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:701)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:667)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:715)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:590)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:529)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:169)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1124)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1079)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:761)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:133)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:791)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
    PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'driverClassName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver]
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:122)
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:77)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1681)
        ... 37 more

    16-Jan-2019 18:15:33.907 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-6] org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean Initializing Servlet 'dispatcher'
    16-Jan-2019 18:15:34.025 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-6] org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myDataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
    PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'driverClassName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver]
    16-Jan-2019 18:15:34.026 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-6] org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean Context initialization failed
     org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myDataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
    PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'driverClassName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1685)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1400)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:575)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:846)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:701)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:667)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:715)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:590)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:529)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:169)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1124)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1079)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:761)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:133)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:791)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
    PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'driverClassName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver]
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:122)
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:77)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1681)
        ... 37 more

    16-Jan-2019 18:15:34.200 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-7] org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean Initializing Servlet 'dispatcher'
    16-Jan-2019 18:15:34.262 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-7] org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myDataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
    PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'driverClassName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver]
    16-Jan-2019 18:15:34.262 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-7] org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean Context initialization failed
     org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myDataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
    PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'driverClassName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1685)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1400)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:575)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:846)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:701)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:667)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:715)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:590)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:529)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:169)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1124)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1079)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:761)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:133)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:791)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
    PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'driverClassName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver]
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:122)
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:77)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1681)
        ... 37 more

    16-Jan-2019 18:15:38.090 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\Users\c\Downloads\apache-tomcat-9.0.13-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.13\webapps\manager]
    16-Jan-2019 18:15:38.151 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Users\c\Downloads\apache-tomcat-9.0.13-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.13\webapps\manager] has finished in [61] ms
```

This code connects with SQL SERVER:

```
package pl.c.testdb;

import java.sql.*;

public class MSSQL {
    public static void getDbConnection() {
        try {

            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;integratedSecurity=true;");
            if (conn != null) {
                DatabaseMetaData metaObj = conn.getMetaData();
                System.out.println("Driver Name?= " + metaObj.getDriverName() + ", Driver Version?= " + metaObj.getDriverVersion() + ", Product Name?= " + metaObj.getDatabaseProductName() + ", Product Version?= " + metaObj.getDatabaseProductVersion());
                Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM PraceDyplomowe.dbo.Student");
                while (rs.next())
                    System.out.println(rs.getString(2));
            }
        } catch (Exception sqlException) {
            sqlException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        getDbConnection();
    }
}
```

These are environmental variables (I use solution from here and it did not work: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brian_swan/2011/03/02/getting-started-with-the-sql-server-jdbc-driver/)

[Environmental Variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1fPs.png)

Comment: The error suggests the driver is not on the classpath

Comment: This is a problem of deployment on Tomcat or something environmental of system?

Comment: You have access to your systems, we don't. We can't tell.

Comment: I did it like they wrote there: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brian_swan/2011/03/02/getting-started-with-the-sql-server-jdbc-driver/

Comment: Those instructions are 'nice' if you want to try a basic Java programming, but things like the `CLASSPATH` environment variable are ignored for most 'real' Java programs including Tomcat. Unzip the war generated by gradle, and check if the Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver is in the `WEB-INF/lib` folder; also make sure your Tomcat is running on Java 8.

Comment: If the driver is properly placed in the WAR file, it will be automatically added to the classpath (and assuming the driver version you specified works on your java version), eg 7.0.0.jre8 works on Java 8, but not earlier Java versions, and for Java 10 and higher it would be better to use 7.0.0.jre10.

Comment: Aaaa, ok. I have there some libraries as you said, how can I include there more libraries? I thought that gradle does it automatically.

Comment: Yeah that's right, I work on Java 8.

Comment: You're right, it normally should include them automatically.

Comment: I do not see mssql-jdbc-7.0.0.jre8.jar in WEB-INF/lib, but i include compile group: 'com.microsoft.sqlserver', name: 'mssql-jdbc', version: '7.0.0.jre8' in build.gradle, so why is that?

Comment: Which gradle version are you using?

Comment: I use Gradle 5.1.1

Comment: When I put these jars by coping them it works because I get now "nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerDriver has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 54.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0 (unable to load class [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver])", so thank you very much!

Comment: But still do not know why it does not deploy automatically. My Gradle configutation is written above.

Comment: I'm not sure why it wouldn't be included by Gradle, I'll see if I can reproduce. However, that `UnsupportedClassVersionError` would suggest you are using the 7.0.0.jre10 version not the 7.0.0.jre8 version, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi

Comment: Yes, I put two version for JAVA 8 and 10, when I deleted this for 10 everything went excellent!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to put mssql-jdbc-7.0.0.jre8.jar lib into deployed war's folder WEB-INF/lib, because gradle does not do it automatically.